# Lower than expected performance of graphics card

Tags: windows, drivers, graphics-card, performance, directx

Can anyone explain why my 3dMark Fire Strike Standard Score is so low?

Hardware:

- MSI GF65 Laptop (New)
- i5-10500 Geforce 3060 laptop
- Ram: 8 GB DDR4
- Nvidea Driver 516.59 (see update below)

Software:

- Windows 10 Resolution: 1920 x 1080
- MSI Dragon Center active, set to Extreme Performance Mode
- No adjustment to Fire Strike Standard settings, just ran it
- No significant programs loaded into memory, other than Steam, which is required
- Expected Result, from notebookcheck.com & 3dMark

Minimum: 15062
Average: 18444
Median: 18597
My (average) Result (after multiple tries, restarts, driver reinstallation, disabling of integrated graphics): **9644**

Note also that game tests also agree with this score (the performance is much less than what should be expected).

I noticed that GPU utilization is very low in most games, so this is obviously related. Throttle Stop & MSI Dragon Center did not help with this. However, Microsoft Flight Simulator 2020 is giving an expected frame rate and it's GPU utilization if 90% plus, so I don't know why there is a discrepancy.

UPDATE: I upgraded my graphics drivers to 528.02 (the most recent version) and  3dMark worked, giving an appropriate 15,880 score (fire strike standard - same test indicated above) but the next day it returned to the original slow performance.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you already did most of the recommended steps, but I think one is missing: Before installing the newest drivers, try uninstalling all of the old ones with [DDU](https://www.guru3d.com/files-details/display-driver-uninstaller-download.html). Otherwise there might be more than one version present in the system, leading to inconsistent behavior

Comment: Not sure if this is the same, but when installing the driver I checked "do a clean install" or some such.

Comment: Likely will accomplish the same thing, except for the driver for the integrated graphics card

Comment: Your update made it sound like it definitely is a driver issue, that why I suggested the complete uninstall with DDU. Best to do that while booted into safe mode btw.

But there are some other things you can try. Subpar performance can also be about thermal or power-throttling. Did you monitor the GPU temps during the run? Are you using the original power-brick? Have you tried updating the BIOS?